How to resolve MojoExecutionException after I tried to run this cmnd "mvn spring-boot:run"?
After mvn clean install was sucessful and I tried to run it using cmd "mvn spring-boot:run" and faced some errors. Pasted the error stack and the pom file details below. Also I tried changing the spring version to 3.1.0 but faced other problems like javax exceptions, however the end goal is to use spring 2.4.3 and maven 3.6.3.
The error stack
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.928 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-10-10T15:15:27+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:run (default-cli) on project ih-pmsc-inbound-oxi: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:run (default-cli) on project ih-pmsc-inbound-oxi: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

The pom details of the file
With spring version : 2.4.3. maven version 3.6.3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
    <artifactId>ih-pmsc-inbound-oxi</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ih-pmsc-inbound-oxi</name>
    <description>Pmsc Inbound OXI Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <pmsc.version>21.0</pmsc.version>
        <spring.version>2.4.3</spring.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.2</quartz.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Production ready -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TC dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
            <artifactId>crypto</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- use this one only if TC-Commons-All not being used -->
            <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
            <artifactId>tc-metrics-collector</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
            <artifactId>tc-metrics-collector-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travelclick.pmsconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>ih-pmsc-common</artifactId>
            <version>${pmsc.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
                    <artifactId>CoreServices</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss.aop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-aop-jdk50</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travelclick</groupId>
            <artifactId>TC-DataAccessCache</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amadeus.ihotelier.kafkaproducer</groupId>
            <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fiorano</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fmq-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fiorano</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fiorano-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travelclick.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-client</artifactId>
            <version>16.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


